# Scaling horizontally but not vertically

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I have a black shape like this:

[image]

That red rectangle is not part of my shape. I just draw it so that divides my shape visually into two parts. I would like to only scale "the part of my shape inside red rectangle" horizontally (I do not want to scale "the part of the shape outside rectangle" horizontally). How can I do this in illustrator?

Comment: this just like the Arabic calligraphy ending vanished point. you don't have so many choices. Convert your path to an outline stroke and reshape your nodes and handles

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about Illustrator -- Grab the **Direct Selection Tool** (the White arrow) and click the anchor points on the left, and move them. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Direct selection tool(shortcut : A).

Click on the object.

Anchor points will be shown.

Now carefully click on the anchor point.

Use arrow key to move the anchor point together in the direction desired